# React Native Debugger Broke

Tags: react-native, expo

I was just coding away, when suddenly the debugger broke and every time I try to reload my app via Expo, cmd shows me the following error:

[image]

I am new to react native, hence clueless what might be wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that remote JS debugging was activated via the developer menu on the phone. I must have accidentally tapped it when reloading the app.